# String Declaration

Tags: c++, string, pointers, stl

String declaration works when I declare in the the following ways:

```
string a = "xyz";
char a[] = "xyz";
```

But in case of:

```
char *a = "xyz";
```

It gives an ERROR in g++ 4.9.2 compiler:

> warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
>   [-Wwrite-strings]   char *a = "xyz";

I think these three declaration types are different from each other. Please help me out.

Comment: It's a warning, not an ERROR. The word "warning" is the clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string a = "xyz";
```

This uses initializer syntax to invoke the constructor `std::string( const char* )`.

```
char a[] = "xyz";
```

This declares an array large enough to store the string plus terminator.  It follows standard array-initializer rules.  Think of it as equivalent to `char a[] = { 'x', 'y', 'z', '\0' };`

```
char *a = "xyz";
```

This takes a string literal (`"xyz"`) and assigns it to a *non-constant* pointer.  Within the language, such a pointer means it is okay to modify the string it points to, but that is *undefined behaviour* in this case, because string literals may not be modified.  To prevent you from making such a mistake, the compiler gives you a warning.  The following is valid and will not emit a warning:

```
const char *a = "xyz";
```

Answer (score 2):

In earlier version(s) of the language, you could use:

```
char* a = "xyz";
```

Now, you must use:

```
char const* a = "xyz";
```

A string literal, such as `"xyz"` resides in the rea-only parts of the program. It can be used to initialize a `char const*` since you are not supposed to modify the contents of what a `char const*` points to. Using it to initialize a `char*` opens the possibility of a user modifying them accidentally. In addition, modifying such strings is cause for undefined behavior.

A string literal can also be used to initialize a `char[]`. In that case, the string literal is copied to the space allocated for the array. Hence, there is no risk of modifying read-only data of the program. Hence, using

```
char a[] = "xyz";
```

is OK.

The line

```
string a = "xyz";
```

invokes the constructor of `string` that takes a `char const*` and then uses that object to initialize `a`. Hence, that line is also OK.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer was downvoted.  It's clear, correct, and even offers a bit of history.

Comment: @paddy, me neither. Hopefully they will explain it :)

Comment: RSahu and  @paddy both of your answer help me a lot to understand the problem. Thank you for your responses. :)

Comment: @biswasJUCSE, glad we were able to help.